# Create a jsonp object dynamically in javascript(Send json object to Cross Domain)

Tags: json, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

I am trying to send a json object to a servlet .

but it is showing error like this:
**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http: //192.168.10.113:8080/collective-intellegence/SaveFeedback. Origin http: //192.168.9.185 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin**

**My Code**

```
var feedbackData = [];

        for (j in storeData.collection) {
            var fromData="abc";
            feedbackData.push({
                "queryid": queryId,
                "from": fromData,
                "to": GetUserDetails(storeData.item(j)),
                "isresolved": document.getElementById(("chk" + j)).checked
            });
        }
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: saveDataURL,
                data: "{ 'feedback': '" + feedbackData + "' }",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Success');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });
```

This is showing ERROR

i Googled and found that we can't pass json object to a cross domain.

so i decided to create a jsonp object which i can pass to cross domain .

please help to solve the problem

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the Datatype to **JSONP**

```
function hello(data){ // my call back function
            console.log(data);
        }

        $(function(){
            //It's not actually working, but htis code should work well
            //Let's say that you put your docStats in an object
            //like docStats = data.response.clickStats.docStats

            $.ajax({
                url:'http://example.com',
                type : 'POST' ,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data : {
                    fq: 'param1',
                    wt: 'param2',
                    "json.wrf" : 'hello' // how i call my callback function

                }
            });

        })
```

Comment: if i do jsonp ,then servlet is not working bcz it is taking only json format and if i use json in datatype it is showing error i mentioned .

i have to send a json object not jsonp object

Answer (score 0):

You should read about how JSONP works: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Since JSONP works by creating  tags, you can only use JSONP with a GET HTTP method, not POST. And all the data you **send** with JSONP is sent in the URL query parameters (since GET request don't have a body).

I think you should check out CORS and examine if it is a good solution to your cross-origin problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing